# asp.net 5 mvc 6 model issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to list some data from a news section. I have two tables. News and NewsCategory

This is my model classes

```
public class News
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewsCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsCategory NewsCategory { get; set; }
}
public class NewsCategory
{
    public int NewsCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<News> News { get; set; }
}

public class NewsDbContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
    }

    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsCategory> NewsCategory { get; set; }
}
```

This is also working, when I in my controller fect the data, with the exception of one thing. When I fect my news, I do not have a reference to my Category.

My controller code:

```
var news = _db.News.ToList();
```

This outputs :

```
    [
  {
    "NewsId": 1,
    "Name": "ghdfgd",
    "NewsCategoryId": 1,
    "NewsCategory": null
  },
  {
    "NewsId": 2,
    "Name": "gdfgdf",
    "NewsCategoryId": 1,
    "NewsCategory": null
  }
]
```

As you can see, NewsCategory is empty. Although it is not:)

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't set up the foreign key relationship, are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Data.Entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are lazy loading the navigation properties. 
Look into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) article.

Just do this:

```
var news = _db.News.Include(n => n.NewsCategory).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, Yes that will work. However this will load all of the : public virtual List<News> News as well inside the newscategory.

How would I go about excluding the list News from newscategory in this instance?

Comment: @user3820281 that's the default behavior if you have those 2 virtual properties, if you don't need the `News` property just remove it.